# cannot download images in Corona

Tags: image, coronasdk

I using Corona SDK. I parse json and in the listener function I try to load images using links from json, but it says network error. It seems I cannot run network methods in parallel?

Even default corona demo code doesn't work for some reason:

```
local function networkListener2( event )
if ( event.isError ) then
    print ( "Network error - download failed" )
else
    event.target.alpha = 0
    transition.to( event.target, { alpha = 1.0 } )
end

print ( "RESPONSE: " .. event.response )
end

myImage2 = display.loadRemoteImage( 
"http://developer.anscamobile.com/demo/hello.png", 
"GET", 
networkListener2, 
"helloCopy2.png", 
system.TemporaryDirectory, 
60, 280 )
```

it fails to run on android emulator.

Comment: Simultaneous network requests are possible. Provide some code.

Comment: Hmm. Code works well for me.  The image is loaded and a transition from alpha 0 to alpha 1 happends

Comment: on what emulator are you testing? I still cannot load an image.

Comment: Oh! are you running on android emulator?  I am not sure how effectively Corona apps run on the android emulator.   You should test on a device

Comment: I guess the problem maybe with storing file...not sure. So you successfully run this on android device, yes?

Comment: No. I just tested in Corona Simulator.  But I don't see any reason why that should't work on the device. I've used remoteImages previouly on devices.

Comment: Can you please explain remoteImages?

Comment: so you tested on simulator - i.e. iOS simulator?

Comment: corona ios simulator? because there are android and ios ones